# How to make Chrome, Firefox and Opera zoom text in the container flawlessly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am trying to make a form on the web site, which should be edited by user and then printed. Parent `<div>` container should mimick paper size A4, so that everyone can see, what he is going to print. `<div>` dimesions are fixed.  Classic WYSIWYG.

The problems comes, when I zoom page in and out in Opera, Firefox and Chrome. It seems, that the width of the container and the text within resize themselves correctly, but the bottom part shows variations, which considerably affects and undermine my intention.

By the zoom 110% bottom line of text jumps out of container, other values changes footer thickness randomly. There is no prediction, how the container and the text within will behave (AFAIK).

I was spending hours to find solution on the web. I changed measure units (px, em, vm) for font-height and for the container as well. Nothing helped. It seems, that line height of the text is always integer, so when text is resized, overall sum of line heights can have discrete and distinct values, which do not truly reflects resized height of the parent container.

This severely influences design and makes "erroneous" user experience.

Chrome zoom 100%
[image]

Chrome zoom 110%
[image]

Chrome zoom 125%
[image]

Here I provide test code. Try to zoom in and zoom out (tested in Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m, Opera 35.0.2066.68 - Windows 7; Firefox 44.0.2 - Windows XP).

**AND !!!! To my big surprise IE 11.0.9600.17728 zooms this astonishingly correctly !!!!!???? Extremely nice.**
I am really perplexed.

Thanks for advices

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div contentEditable="true" style = "position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width:280px; height:350px; border: 2px; background-color:#FAF; font-size: 16px">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempor est non venenatis rutrum. Aliquam eros lorem, rutrum id porta eget, scelerisque ut augue. Vestibulum nulla tortor, ultrices ut molestie sed, sollicitudin at justo. Praesent consectetur augue justo, ut sollicitudin leo porttitor at. Duis dignissim metus sed posuere convallis. Proin sagittis lobortis metus, ut lobortis sem viverra lobortis. Donec eget tempus magna.
</span><p>
<b>Curabitur vehicula, risus at finibus venenatis, neque justo viverra purus, vitae suscipit lacus arcu in magna. In tempus justo mattis arcu laoreet finibus. Nam imperdiet leo pharetra, feugiat nisl sed, feugiat felis. Pellentesque interdum egestas lobortis. </b>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I found out, the only correct way to make zooming run fluently without glitches is to apply -webkit-transform: scale(); for desired element and forbid browser to apply native zoom function (not tested, just a proposal). This works in Opera, Chrome at least.

Here is example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=1;

    function Adjust(){
    el = document.getElementById("targ");
    a = a + 0.01;
    el.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + a + ')';

}

</script>
<body>
<button onclick="Adjust()">Adjust</button> 
<div id="targ" contentEditable="true" style = "position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; width:280px; height:350px; border: 2px; background-color:#FAF; font-size: 16px; -webkit-transform: scale(1); "> <!--   -webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px);  -->
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempor est non venenatis rutrum. Aliquam eros lorem, rutrum id porta eget, scelerisque ut augue. Vestibulum nulla tortor, ultrices ut molestie sed, sollicitudin at justo. Praesent consectetur augue justo, ut sollicitudin leo porttitor at. Duis dignissim metus sed posuere convallis. Proin sagittis lobortis metus, ut lobortis sem viverra lobortis. Donec eget tempus magna.
</span><p>
<b>Curabitur vehicula, risus at finibus venenatis, neque justo viverra purus, vitae suscipit lacus arcu in magna. In tempus justo mattis arcu laoreet finibus. Nam imperdiet leo pharetra, feugiat nisl sed, feugiat felis. Pellentesque interdum egestas lobortis. </b>
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```